# Is it true that Ukrainian swearing vocabulary was replaced by a Russian one?

Tags: ненормативна-лексика

I was told that a long time ago Ukrainian swearing was based primarily around act of defecation and *ass* (*срака*) itself. But nowadays you can rarely hear that. Instead *cunt* (*пизда*), *dick* (*хуй*) and their derivatives are used all over the place.

Are there any studies on what was the reason / push for moving towards genital based swearing? Was that indeed Russian influence? Or maybe it happened as a result of internal changes in Ukrainian society (for example, Ukrainians nowadays are far less religious than before)?

Comment: Based on what I read, Russians tend to blame Mongolians for bringing these words to them. Which makes me think that everyone just says "no, those dirty words are not ours!".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, while, on the one hand, it's right that the Russian language greatly influenced the Ukrainian language and many Ukrainian-native swearing words/phrases were ousted by Russian words/phrases — we, on the other hand, should not treat common Slavic swearing lexicon as non-Ukrainian (just because Russians use them too).

The words “хуй”, “пизда”, “їбати”, “блядь” аre not exclusively-Russian, they're part of common Slavic lexicon:

- “хуй” — Russian, Belarusian, Bulgarian “хуй”, Czech, Polish, Slovak “chuj”, Kashubian “chùj”. From Proto-Slavic “*xujь”. Sources: [1](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.91.D0.BB.D1.8F.D0.B4.D1.8C), [2](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9#Etymology_3), [3](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/xuj%D1%8C).
- “пизда” — Belarusian “пізда”, Russian “пизда”, Serbo-Croatian “pizda”/“пизда”, Slovene, Czech, Polish, Slovak “pizda”. Cognates: Old Prussian “peisda”, Lithuanian “pyzda” and Latvian “pīzda”. From Proto-Slavic “*pizda”, from Proto-Balto-Slavic “*pīˀsdāˀ”, from Proto-Indo-European “*písdeh₂”. Sources: [1](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.91.D0.BB.D1.8F.D0.B4.D1.8C), [2](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0#Etymology), [3](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/pizda).
- “їбати” — Belarusian “ябаць”, Russian “ебать”, “еть”, Bulgarian “еба”, Macedonian “е́бе”, Serbo-Croatian “јебати”/“jebati”, Slovene “jebati”, Czech “jebat”, Polish “jebać”, Slovak “jebať”, Slovincian “jåbac”, Lower Sorbian “jebaś”, Upper Sorbian “jebać”. From Proto-Slavic “*jěbati”, from Proto-Indo-European “*h₃yebʰ-”. Sources: [1](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.91.D0.BB.D1.8F.D0.B4.D1.8C), [2](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#Etymology), [3](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/j%C4%9Bbati).
- “блядь” — Belarusian “блядзь”, Russian “блядь”. Cognates: Polish “blędzieć”, Old Czech “blesti”, Lower Sorbian “blada”, Upper Sorbian “bledzić”, Polabian “blǫdә”, Serbo-Croatian “blesti”, “blediti”, Slovene “blesti”. From Old East Slavic “блѧдь”, from Proto-Slavic “*blędь”, from “*blęsti”. Sources: [1](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#.D0.91.D0.BB.D1.8F.D0.B4.D1.8C), [2](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%8C#Etymology), [3](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%A7%D0%B4%D1%8C#Old_East_Slavic).

Other less tabooed words, which some may also think as having Russian origin, are in fact common, e.g.:

- “сука”, “сучий”: Но зла Юнона, суча дочка, / розкудкудакалась, як квочка, / Енея не любила — страх; / давно вона уже хотіла, / щоб його душка полетіла / к чортам і щоб і дух не пах. *<sub>//I. Kotliarevskyi “Eneyida” (1798).</sub>*
- “чорт”: Ти, султан, чорт турецкий, і проклятого чорта брат і товариш, самого Люцеперя секретар. *<sub>//Allegedly from the letter of the Zaporozhian Cossacks to Turkish Sultan (1676).</sub>*

On the other hand, it seems to be true that many native Ukrainian swearing words/phrases, which are local to Ukrainian only, were forgotten or partially forgotten due to displacement by Russian or common lexicon.

Answer (score 14):

For sure, Ukrainian swearing vocabulary was influenced and extended by Russian and English (thanks to Hollywood) swearing cultures. As a result, you will be able to find a very interesting combinations or Ukrainian, Russian and English swearwords.

But still, Ukrainian swearing vocabulary is mostly *ass*-centered (it's more close to English swearing culture) while Russian one is *genitals*-centered.

Here is a good [explanation](http://archive.prostory.net.ua/ru/articles/481-2012-01-23-12-58-29):

> Лайливу лексику В. Мокієнко класифікує за двома типами:
>   "анально-екскремальний" (Scheiss-культура) та "сексуальний"
>   (Sex-культура). До першої В. Мокієнко відносить: чеську, німецьку,
>   англійську, французьку, **українську**. До другого типу належать:
>   **російська**, сербська, болгарська та хорватська. Приналежність
>   російської мови до сексуального типу пояснюється тим, що ядро
>   російського мату складається трьох найбільш часто уживаних слів: `хуй` –
>   `пизда` – `ебать`.
>
> У словнику "Нецензурної лексики української мови та її відповідників"
>   Л. Ставицька стверджує, що в українській мові домінує обсценна лексика
>   зі **скатологічною (екскремальною) домінантою**: "про це переконливо
>   свідчить приблизне кількісне співвідношення сталих словосполучень,
>   зафіксованих у пропонованому Словнику, на базі двох обсценних сфер:
>   `їбати`, `їбатися` – до 20, `срати` – 46, `пизда` – 38, `хуй` – 57, `срака` – 151,
>   `жопа` – 76.
>
> В умовах глобалізації та міграційних процесів межі між різними
>   обсценними культурами стають дифузними, взаємнопроникними; переклади
>   іноземних фільмів, масова культура транспонують інновації,
>   трансформують питомі традиції інвективи. Приміром, як зазначає В.
>   Мокієнко, у російській лінгвокультурі помітнішим стає скатологічний
>   елемент. Це зокрема відбувається через переклад англомовних фільмів,
>   оскільки обсценна лексика англійської мови має скатологічний характер.
>   Українська обсценна лайка знаходиться під впливом одночасно і
>   російської, й англійської обсценної лайки. Так, сучасна молодь схильна
>   вживати багато англійської лайки: серед яких головними є слова `shit` і
>   `fuck`.

I also recommend [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRkzPTqZ-Dk) with some additional insights.

Comment: This answer would benefit from translation the extended quote to English. Can anyone help?